# How do I use PowerShell to stop and start a clustered "Generic Service"?

Tags: powershell

How do I use PowerShell to stop and start a "Generic Service" as seen in the Microsoft "Cluster Administrator" software?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use WMI. You can get all the Generic Services with:

```
$services = Get-WmiObject -Computer "Computer" -namespace 'root\mscluster' `
MSCluster_Resource | Where {$_.Type -eq "Generic Service"}
```

To stop and start a service:

```
$timeout = 15
$services[0].TakeOffline($timeout)
$services[0].BringOnline($timeout)
```

Comment: Great...But when executing I got some admin error. So I added this parameter `-Authentication PacketPrivacy` and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the answer is to simply use the command line tool CLUSTER.EXE to do this:

cluster RES MyGenericServiceName /OFF

cluster RES MyGenericServiceName /ON